# How to add chatter page in Communities

Tags: visualforce, community

I am using SFDC + VF tabs community template. I created a custom home page for communities.

I want to add Chatter link in that page so when ever user click on that page it should open chatter page for that partner user so that he can view chatter feed and post some messages on chatter.

Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Visualforce page I created with chatter feed.

```
    <apex:page standardStylesheets="true" sidebar="true" showHeader="false">
        <style type="text/css">
           .hideButton{display:none;}
        </style>
           <chatter:feedWithFollowers entityId="{!$User.Id}"/>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [answer]. If you can add an explanation, that will make your answer much more valuable to the community.